# How to maintain state of a page in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-web

my app has a drawer and in it, i change pages based on an integer (to track the index) and not by Navigating from one page to other. i tried using the AuthomaticKeepAlive but it does works there. is there any other way to it?

Comment: It's always better to add some code and more details. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**You can simple achieve this using stateful widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleDrawerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleDrawerPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SimpleDrawerPageState createState() => _SimpleDrawerPageState();
}

class _SimpleDrawerPageState extends State<SimpleDrawerPage> {
  final pagesMenu = ["Home", "Settings"];
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        switch (pageIndex) {
          case 1:
            return SettingsPage();
          // case 2:
          //   return SecondPage();
          // case 3:
          //   return ThirdPage();
          default:
            // here we use [default] for [index 0] ;
            return HomePage();
        }
      }),
      drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: pagesMenu.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(pagesMenu.elementAt(index)),
                    tileColor: index == pageIndex ? Colors.teal : null,
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        pageIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                  ))),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Center(child: Text('HomePage')));
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Center(child: Text('SettingsPage')));
  }
}
```

Comment: no i mean actual state of the screen in which it is rendered for the first time. i do not want it to call init state every time it loads on first time.

Answer (score 0):

**I got the answer from another Question**

there are 2 ways to do it
**1st Method**
First way is to use a pageview widget on top of the children pages and use
pageview controller to change the page index. Obviously you have to use AutomaticKeepAliveStateMixin to main the state of pages to want to maintain state
**2nd Method**
The other way which is simple and handy is to use indexedStack widget and provide it a set of children(pages) and current page index. it simply keeps all its children in stack and do not loose its state.